# disable related button if any field in class is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fetching data with ajax in which every `tr` have a related button, if there is any empty field in class, I want to disable its closest button.
I tried this code,which is not disabling button.

```
success:function(response) {      

            var cat = {};
            response.result.forEach(function(element) {
              cat[element.category] = cat[element.category] || [];
              cat[element.category].push(element);
            });

            Object.keys(cat,).forEach(function(category) {
            // Append the category header   
                html = '<tr>';
                html += '<th><p>'+category+'</p></th>';
                html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);

        // Loop through the results for this category
          categ[category].forEach(function(element) {
            console.log(element);
            var id = element.id;
            var score= element.score;
                            var catID= element.cat_id;

                html = '<tr class="data">'; 
                html += '<td  class"=ids"><p>'+id+'</p></td>';
                html += '<td><p>'+score+'</p></td>';
                html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);
        });
                html = '<tr>';  
                html += '<input type="hidden" value="'+catID+'" />';
                html += '<td> <button type="button" class="submitOne> </button> submit </td>';
                html += '</tr>';
                $('table').append(html);
        });
}
```

Script for disabling button

```
$(function () {
$('.data').each(function () {
    if ( !$.trim($(this).find('.ids').html() ).length ) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.submitOne').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    else {
        (this).closest('tr').find('.submitOne').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Could you also post a snippet of the related HTML, it would help in debugging

Comment: please provide your html content and tell us what is happening with your code @lipon

Comment: @NijinKoderi I am trying to disable button with every empty element of class, but a I am not getting it done with above code. but its not giving any error.

Comment: @lipon is it going to your if and else condition correctly? can you put a console and check

Comment: @NijinKoderi yes i checked it

Comment: im checking give me  5 min @lipon

Comment: @NijinKoderi ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you **missed is a double quote** in button class

```
<td> <button type="button" class="submitOne> </button> submit </td>
```

replace with

```
<td> <button type="button" class="submitOne"> </button> submit </td>
```

and use **next()** instead of **closet()**

```js
$(function () {
$('.data').each(function () {
   if ( !$.trim($(this).find('.ids').html() ).length ) {
   console.log("a")
    $(this).next('tr').find('.submitOne').prop('disabled', true);


    }
    else {
    console.log("b")
    $(this).next('tr').find('.submitOne').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
});
```